Switching power and controlling RPi GPIO pins with a single rocker switch
I have a 12V amplifier board with the sound source being a raspberry pi.  I'd like to have a single rocker on/off switch that both turns off power to the board, as well as connect to the RPi GPIO pins to send a shutdown command on off, rather than cut the power directly to the Pi.  Is there a way to do both these on a single switch?

There are a couple options, the first one perhaps you haven't considered.
It should be possible to configure the RPi with a read-only file system (if your application doesn't need to write to disk), and then The RPi should be fine with just cutting the power.
https://learn.adafruit.com/read-only-raspberry-pi/overview
Otherwise, look into a power controller chip, whereas the chip monitors user IO (power On/Off button) and tells the RPi time to turn off. The RPi, or perhaps the controller chip could also turn off your amp. The chip also monitors for a power-on request (your button), and then powers everything back up.
A random Linear Tech device that I've used in the past (there are many out there that would likely be a better choice for your application):

Image from: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc2955.html
Good luck!
