Shut down raspberry when unplugged from power thanks to a battery
Context and objective
I need to properly shut down a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W when it is (physically) unplugged from the power and power it on again automatically when it is plugged back.
The basic idea to address this issue is to use a battery that keeps the raspberry powered on long enough for it to shut down properly.
Question
Do you think it could work? To clarify, I would like to know if this circuit would achieve the results of:

turning on the raspberry as soon as the circuit is plugged into the power supply
triggering the shutdown command upon disconnection from power supply

How it works
Here is how it works:

I am powering everything with a TP4056
When the TP4056 is plugged, it provides power to the battery and to the raspberry - and turns on an LED on the TP4056 itself
An optoisolator LTV817 is given power by the aforementioned LED on the TP4056, so that the LTV817 can give 5v to the raspberry as soon as the whole circuit is plugged
GPIO17 is an input: it receives its high status the led of the TP4056. When the TP4056 is unplugged, the led turns off and GPIO27 is not high anymore and can send the halt signal to safely turn off the raspberry
GPIO27 is an output: it is set HIGH as soon as boot is completed and keeps the LTV817 powered so that, when power is pulled from the circuit, the raspberry has time to shut down properly
There is a switch to allow to turn on the circuit even without plugging it

See a kind of sketch of the schematic below.


please add a focused, answerable question to your post

I tried to clarify the question. I just would like to know if the circuit makes sense and if it would work as espected, that is, properly shut down a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W when it is (physically) unplugged from the power and power it on again automatically when it is plugged back.

I can’t decipher your wiring diagram (please draw a schematic), but can you sense if 5 V is present from USB? That would be my suggestion and use software in your RPi to trigger shutdown.

Similar, but different:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708620/switching-power-and-controlling-rpi-gpio-pins-with-a-single-rocker-switch
